# IOS SDK Epson Printer - How to adjust left and right margin in print receipt?

Tags: ios, swift, margins, thermal-printer, epson

I'm implement a custom design of the receipt,Create image from the view and image size is 400*600.

I want to decrease left and right margin,Even i increase width for image but not decrease margin in  print receipt.

My printer printing width: 72mm and Character per line: 48/64

[Please check this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozZdd.jpg)

Please help, I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

is there any method available for adjust margin? Use this SDK (https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=7031&scat=58&pcat=52).

Comment: check their Sample Project ePOS2_Printer in the SDK folder

Comment: @QuangHà Yes, Check this project but i want adjust image margin. is there any method ?